Grouped rolling average
What is the solution for calculating a rolling average for a numerical variable that is observed for two groups over three periods?
df <- data.frame(
  Day = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  Num = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 9)
)

The dplyr solution is easy enough, but is there an obvious way to do this in base?
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(RollingAvg = (Num + lag(Num))/2)


Would you consider the “zoo” package to be a base solution?

Yes, but I am new to R so welcome any information that would change my mind about what is and isn't base R.

Note that for rolling mean, you could use stats::filter which is loaded by default thus could be considered part of base R:
transform(df, RollingAve = ave(Num, Id, FUN = \(x)stats::filter(x, rep(1,2)/2,sides = 1)))

  Day Id Num RollingAve
1   1  A   1         NA
2   2  A   2        1.5
3   3  A   3        2.5
4   1  B   1         NA
5   2  B   3        2.0
6   3  B   9        6.0


If you do not like to write a wrapper (b_lag) which does what dplyr::lag() does, you can use embed(). Try ave():
b_lag = \(x, k, fill = NA) c(rep(fill, k), head(x, -k))
within(df, { RollingAvg = ave(Num, Id, FUN = \(x) (x + b_lag(x, 1)) / 2) })

giving
  Day Id Num RollingAvg
1   1  A   1         NA
2   2  A   2        1.5
3   3  A   3        2.5
4   1  B   1         NA
5   2  B   3        2.0
6   3  B   9        6.0

Note. within() is used to generate the output as is. You could also do
df$RollingAvg = with(df, ave(Num, Id, FUN = \(x) (x + b_lag(x, 1)) / 2))


Using transform/ave/filter as in @Onyambu's solution seems most straight forward and readily generalizes to arbitrary n but it might be useful to see a variety of alternatives to get a feel of what is possible.  The problem decomposes into calculating a rolling mean of 2 and performing the grouping.
Rolling Mean
For the rolling mean of 2 any of these would work.  The embed solution is referred to in @Friede's answer without code so we show code here.  The filter approach is shown in @Onyambu's answer but repeated here for comparison.  We have added c(...) to it so that its result is an ordinary vector rather than ts class but ave would have done that for us anyways. For the solution using lag note that lag in base R is not the same as lag in dplyr.  The base R lag works with ts objects.  The embed and filter solutions can be readily generalized to arbitrary n.
mean2a <- function(x) c(NA, rowMeans(embed(x, 2))) 

mean2b <- function(x) c(stats::filter(x, c(1,1)/2,,1)) # @Onyambu

mean2c <- function(x) diff( c(NA, 0, cumsum(x)), 2) / 2

mean2d <- function(x) c(NA, x[-1] + x[-length(x)]) ) / 2

mean2e <- function(x) ( c(NA, x) + c(x, NA) )[seq_along(x)] / 2

mean2f <- function(x) { y <- ts(x); c(NA, y + stats::lag(y)) / 2 }

mean2g <- function(x) sapply(seq_along(x), \(i) if (i==1) NA else mean(x[i-0:1]))

In a comment you suggested that although the question refers to base R you might still wish to consider packages so if we interpret that not using dplyr but allowing other packages then an example would be:
library(zoo)
mean2h <- function(x) rollmeanr(x, 2, fill = NA)

Grouping
The grouping part can be done with ave as in @Onyambu or using by.  do.call("rbind", lapply(split(...))) and within (@Friede) would also work.  We will show the first two where mean2 is any of the above:
df |>
  transform(mean2 = ave(Num, Id, FUN = mean2))


transform_by <- function(x, by, ...) {
  do.call("rbind", by(x, x[by], transform, ...))
}
df |> transform_by("Id", mean2 = mean2(Num))

Note
df <- data.frame(
  Day = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  Num = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 9)
)

